# Setting a wildcard in ESP8266WebServer

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I want to send all paths that start with "/robot" to a certain handler using ESP8266WebServer.h. I tried a few variations:

```
server.on ( "/robot", handleDirection );
server.on ( "/robot/", handleDirection );
server.on ( "/robot/*", handleDirection );
```

But in each case, it only listens for the exact path (including the * for that one).

Does this library just not support wildcard paths? Or am I missing how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

This is very easy in OO way

```
class MyHandler : public RequestHandler {

  bool canHandle(HTTPMethod method, String uri) {
    return uri.startsWith( "/robot" );
  }

  bool handle(ESP8266WebServer& server, HTTPMethod requestMethod, String requestUri) {    
    doRobot( requestUri );
    server.send(200, "text/plain", "Yes!!");
    return true;
  }

} myHandler;

...
  server.addHandler( &myHandler );
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround in an example. I can have my not found handler examine the uri directly and handle this case. IE,

```
void handleDirection(String path) {
  int index = path.lastIndexOf('/');
  String direction = path.substring(index, path.length());
  Serial.println(direction);
}

void handleNotFound() {
  String path = server.uri();
  int index = path.indexOf("/robot");
  if (index >= 0) {
    handleDirection(path);
  }

  returnNotFound();
}

void setup() {
    [...]
    server.onNotFound ( handleNotFound );
    [...]
}
```

It works for now. I'll leave the question unanswered in case someone else finds the right way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

You can achieve this by doing the following using regular expressions:

```
#include <uri/UriRegex.h>

web_server.on(UriRegex("/home/([0-9]+)/first"), HTTP_GET, [&]() {
    web_server.send(200, "text/plain", "Hello from first! URL arg: " + web_server.pathArg(0));
});

web_server.on(UriRegex("/home/([0-9]+)/second"), HTTP_GET, [&]() {
    web_server.send(200, "text/plain", "Hello from second! URL arg: " + web_server.pathArg(0));
});
```

Then try to call the URLs like this:

```
http://<IP ADDRESS>/home/123/first
```

Then you should see the following in your browser!

> Hello from first! URL arg: 123

**Please notice that every [RegEx group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) will correspond to a `pathArg`.**

#### More options:

After checking the source code of Arduino framework for ESP, and according to the following [file](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WebServer/src/uri/UriRegex.h), [pull request](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/pull/5214) and [issue](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2019) on GitHub, it is stated in [this](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2019#issuecomment-445632993) comment that you have three options:

> Option 1: proposal by @Bmooij with custom "{}" for wildcard and pathArgs in #5214
> Option 2: glob style pattern matching, which is super standard and used in most shells in #5467
> Option 3: regex pattern matching, which is also super standard, although a bit more complex.

Comment: this is by far the best way to do it! Thanks